# url parameters are not in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitch

I want to get information from the TwitchTV OAuth API, and the authorization works well, but I can not get the code that Twitch redirects me to.

For example:
`http://localhost/?code=noj4n39487fn29fn23v92hr293hnru23v97hre&scope=`

```
This is how Twitch redirects back to my page. In the log of my rails server it also shows the following:
Started GET "/?code=q5yptiyx3cdaep52b7xyqgt3vjpwhg&scope=" for 371.1721.13.179     at 2015-08-22 17:09:26 +0200
Cannot render console from 315.127.134.179! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1,     127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"q5ypti345ferf2rf2efr2erferfe23ff", "scope"=>""}
  News Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "news".* FROM "news"
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/home (14.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 124ms (Views: 120.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

But when I try to get `params.inspect` in the controller, it shows this:
`{"controller"=>"oauth", "action"=>"index"}`
my controller looks like this:

```
class OauthController < ApplicationController
    def index
        redirect_to 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=34n87fn48fn438rzfghb4z8rofg4rg&redirect_uri=http://localhost/'
        logger.info params.inspect
    end
end
```

Obviously I changed all the ip's, auth-codes and stuff. My question is, shouldn't `params` return the parameters since it shows them as parameters (in the first code block) ?

Answer (score -1):

Localhost is local address and 'outworld' API cannot send information back to 'localhost', you have to use http://127.0.0.1 or get a real domain for you development environment.

Comment: As I said I changed the domain names and ips, I changed my domain-name for localhost, so that nobody can see my real ip and such that's not the problem. Twitch directly redirects me to my site and a s a parameter it gives me this `?code=197f23h97fqf` stuff, but I cant access it. that's the point .... And btw, I've also said the authentication went well.